# border-bottom styling. Make border bottom same width as nav-bar menu

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I am trying to create a horizontal line on my WordPress site that lines up perfectly with my container and text underneath. [see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s78MW.png)

I cannot seem to get it to line up with the body-container of my site. Is there any way to style the bottom-border to make it a width of 200px for eg. ?

Comment: bottom border will be the length of the element it is assigned to. You could make an inner element with a width of 200px.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another div with a fixed width and style it with a bottom-border:

```
<body>
  <div class="bodyContainer">
    <p>This is the main container.</p>
    <div class="borderBottom"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.borderBottom {
  width: 300px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

If your body container has a fixed height, move the .borderBottom div to outside the body container.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use [CSS Pseudo-elements](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) which are [currently supported by all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=pseudo-elements). This will let you remove the extra `div` in your HTML. Example code below:

```
 <div class="bodyContainer">
    <p>This is the main container.</p>
 </div>

.bodyContainer::after {
  content: '';
  width: 200px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
}
```